# Memory allocator for a light tree based data structure for frequent allocation and deallocation

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

I have a binary tree based data structure that does all operations in `O(log N)`. It allocates / deallocates memory via `new` and `delete`. In my typical usage, the data structure is in use for a 40 minutes run and allocates/de-allocates small chunks tree nodes half a billion times. The overall memory footprint of this data structure is low as de-allocation happens soon enough. This has been identified as a performance bottleneck.

I am thinking of overloading operator `new` and `delete` or modifying my existing code to be able to use allocators and create a custom allocator for such purpose. I am thinking of allocating contiguous large amount of memory upfront and re-using chunks of memory from it. Does C++11 standard have such a pool based memory allocator?

What memory allocation/de-allocation strategy would be best suited for such usage?

Comment: Time to move on to pmr of C++17.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box feature in C++11 for memory pooling. But you can use [Boost.Pool](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/introduction.html) to this aim. From the [Boost.Pool](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/introduction.html) Documentation:

> **When should I use Pool?**
>
> Pools are generally used when there is a lot of allocation and deallocation of small objects. Another common
> usage is the situation above, where many objects may be dropped out of
> memory.
> In general, use Pools when you need a more efficient way to do unusual memory control.

Comment: Including a boost library for this purpose seems overkill. In my case, I am ready to implement a naive contrived version of it myself.

Comment: @MukulGupta What do you mean by overkill??

Comment: Including a full fledged library has organizational overhead in my case. Additionally, I would want to be able to know the implementation details of such pool allocators.

Answer (score 0):

Use C++17 [std::pmr::unsynchronized_pool_resource](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unsynchronized_pool_resource) or the synchronized version.